# Calling listener.Accept() Concurrently

Tags: go, tcp

Assuming we are listening on a TCP port (using `listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")` for example), is it OK to call `listener.Accept()` in different goroutines concurrently? Does it help with maximizing accepting speed?

Comment: It should work, but it isn't necessary. The way to maximize `accept()` speed is to do nothing else in the loop except accept connections and start threads. Specifically, don't do any I/O, and that includes anything that could require a DNS lookup. But `accept()` speed isn't an important aspect of server performance, unless you've broken this rule against I/O.

Comment: Thanks; I'm already doing something similar; sending accepted connections to a channel and some acceptors (number of cores) are handling that channel. And it's good. But the documentation of `Accept()` does not say anything if it's safe to get called concurrently (and I went through the source code and it seems safe; but I did not understand it completely).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

net.Listener is a FileDescriptor under the hood. Accept() use Plan9 machinery which guards it with readLock while function and produce connection - newFD. So it looks safe. And because of Lock is read only, no exclusive, you even can get some speedup calling accept concurrently to my mind.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm not a Go's author, just investigate sources.